# How to trace a specific user flow from the complete log file

Tags: java, log4j

The generated log file contains log lines of all the users who accessed the application. Is there any way to trace out (or pull out) the specific log lines which are generated by specific user from a specific IP address?

I am more interested in the following:

- What is the ideal way to log the data to achieve the solution to above problem?
- Is there any good tool that extracts the specific log lines from the complete file based few paraments?
- How to log userId and IP address to each log line? (I know MDC helps but we need to add the required variables before each log statement, which is tedious.)

Note: I dont want to use grep command to extract the required lines from the log file.

FYI, I am using commons-logging and log4j frameworks.

Comment: I theory you could store your ip + userid into a some ThreadLocal variable and create a custom implementation of a Logger that pulls the ip/userid from it and sets the MDC before logging.

Comment: Thats true Claudio but currently my application is already developed and chaning all the current log lines in entire application to custom logger is tedious job. Any alternative way you can suggest here?

Comment: How do you instantiate your loggers?

Comment: Using Commons-logging framework of LogFactory class.

Comment: Actually, according to MDC documentation you don't need to add userid + ip before each line, just once for every thread. If you are in a webapp you can do that at a filter (or similar). (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html).

Comment: Claudio, the mentioned feature is implemented in log4j2.x, do we have anything similary in log4j1.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the solutions for each problem:

- What is the ideal way to log the data to achieve the solution to above problem? 
  [Solution] Add IP address and userId to the log file to achieve
- Is there any good tool that extracts the specific log lines from the complete file based few paraments? 
  [Solution] User log analyzer tools like LogExpert, BairTail or Apache Chainsaw etc.
- How to log userId and IP address to each log line? (I know MDC helps but we need to add the required variables before each log statement, which is tedious.) 
  [Solution] Use servlet filters to configure the required values using MDC. As below:

Java Servlet Filter Code (LogServletFilter.java)

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        MDC.put("userId", "XXXXX");
        MDC.put("ipAddr", "AB.CD.EF.GH");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Log4j.xml

```
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p (%t) [%c{1}] %X{userId} %X{ipAddr} %m%n"/>
  </layout>
```

web.xml

```
      <filter>
      <filter-name>logFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.web.filter.LogServletFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>logFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
```